# Can TeamCity publish a Web project using the sln2008 build runner?

Tags: asp.net, teamcity, deployment, publish

I'm building an ASP.Net MVC project in TeamCity.

Can I somehow call the Publish target and get the output copied to a folder under IIS? or do I need to write an msbuild script for this?

Comment: Maybe this article will help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442374/publish-failed-in-web-application-project-mvc

Comment: That article isn't about TeamCity. I know how to publish, and I know how to do it with msbuild, but I was hoping there was some way to configure TeamCity to do it without needing to write msbuild scripts for every solution.

Answer (score 12):

I've written a pretty long blog post on this very topic that may interest you:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/05/09/automated-site-deployments-with-teamcity-deployment-projects-amp-svn

basically:

- install web deployment projects
- add web deployment project to your solution
- setup the solution configuration manager to have a "Deployment" build configuration
- get team city to use this build switch when running the build
- have a beer and wonder in glory at your automagical awesomenesss

Comment: +1 for the helpful article; I am currently having a glass of water and wondering in glory at my automagical awesomeness :D

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried a [Web Deployment Project](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0AA30AE8-C73B-4BDD-BB1B-FE697256C459&displaylang=en) (WDP)? I have multiple Web Application Projects (WAP) with associated WDPs that work great with TeamCity for deployment scenarios.

I use the sln2008 runner to build my solution (containing both the WAP and the WDP). I've modified the WDP project file (an MSBuild script) to copy the output to a network share:

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Deploy' ">
    <!-- copy WDP output to \\build02\wwwroot\Belden.Web.Intranet\ -->
    <ItemGroup>
        <MySourceFiles Include="$(OutputPath)**\*.*" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(MySourceFiles)" DestinationFiles="@(MySourceFiles->'\\build02\wwwroot\Belden.Web.Intranet\$(ProjectDir)%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)')" />
</Target>
```

I haven't tried this with MVC/WDP, but I imagine it would work the same ...

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can: [Publish sln](http://www.jetbrains.net/confluence/display/TCD4/sln2008). Have a look at the targets. Hopefully it will lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a look at this a while ago but could but had no luck with publishing targets, maybe because my IIS resided on a different server.
Here is how I did it anyway, hope it helps [TeamCity deletes files on build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942267/teamcity-deletes-files-on-build) have a look at the accepted answer.