# Visual Studio. Publish project from command line

Tags: visual-studio, command-line, visual-studio-2010

Is there a way to publish a web project in MS Visual Studio 2010 using CLI? I use DevEnv.exe /Build to build a project and it works fine, but I could not find option to Publish a project.

One other thing I want to mention. I am trying to publish web project NOT to the IIS directly. I have a location where I publish several projects and then build them automatically into NSIS bundle to be deployed.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

What works best is to add following target to the project file:

```xml
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
   <Message Text="Copying to Deployment Dir:" />
   <Copy SourceFiles="@(Content)" DestinationFolder="..\XXX\%(Content.RelativeDir)" />
      <CreateItem Include="$(OutputPath)\*">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Binaries"/>
      </CreateItem>
   <Copy SourceFiles="@(Binaries)" DestinationFolder="..\XXX\bin" />
</Target>
```

This way, whenever project got build (from command line or from IDE) it automatically get deployed to specified folder. Thank you everybody for pointing me to right direction.

Comment: Problem I have with this is that it publishes both debug and release modes doesn't it? That could have serious consequences for a live site if your debug config gets published. Think what we need is a CLI batch that does: 'build Release and Publish with this publish setting'.

Comment: @RobKent you can set up config file transformations which you can then use to trigger the above behavior only for certain build configurations.  Just google .net config transforms.

Comment: does it tale care of  web.config merging?

Answer (score 49):

From [ASP.NET Web Deployment using Visual Studio: Command Line Deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/command-line-deployment), you can use

```
msbuild myproject.csproj /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=MyPublishProfile
```

where `MyPublishProfile` is the profile name that you've already set up somewhere

Comment: `Can't find the valid AspnetMergePath`

Answer (score 6):

The **/t:publish** switch is for **ClickOnce applications only**, it's not applicable to web projects. Hence the error saying it's unpublishable. :)

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @Gusdor It was an answer to the OP, as it originally asked why there was an error saying the solution was 'unpublishable'.

Comment: It wasn't an answer to the OP's question, but a response to his comment on another answer...

Answer (score 0):

@RobKent As https://stackoverflow.com/a/2775437/21233364
using

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Release' ">
   <Message Text="Copying to Deployment Dir:" />
   <Copy SourceFiles="@(Content)" DestinationFolder="..\XXX\%(Content.RelativeDir)" />
      <CreateItem Include="$(OutputPath)\*">
        <Output TaskParameter="Include" ItemName="Binaries"/>
      </CreateItem>
   <Copy SourceFiles="@(Binaries)" DestinationFolder="..\XXX\bin" />
</Target>
```

you can have publish only on release compiling.